# MongoDB not closing connections from NodeJS app

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have a node application that makes a call to mongoDB every 10 seconds, but looking at the output in my terminal, the connections just keep counting up and never seem to close:

My code to hit the ddb every 10 seconds:

```
const MongoClient = require("mongodb").MongoClient
setInterval(function(){
    MongoClient.connect(uri, (err, client) => {
        if (err){
            console.log(err);
        }
        database = client.db(databaseName)
        getData(function(data){
            if(data.length > 0){
                db_response = data;
                params["fieldA"] = db_response[0]['fieldA'];
            }
        })
    })
}, 10000)

function getData(callback){
    var query = { fieldA: "foo" };
    database.collection(CollectionName).find(query).toArray(function(err, result){
        if (err){
            throw err;
        }
        callback(result);
    })
}
```

(The vars uri, CollectionName and databaseName are declared earlier) I guess what i need to do (and havent yet figured out) is to connect to the DB once when the server starts, and then run the getData() function on successful connection, does that mean the database variable needs to be a global var??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you correctly identified you only need to create your db connection once. So rather than wrapping the the db connection creation with `setInterval`, wrap `setInterval` around the only function you want to repeat, in this case `getData`.

On your other question, the database variable doesn't need to global but you are right `getData` does need to use it. Therefore pass it as an argument along with your callback function.

If you want to close your connection use `client.close();` inside `MongoClient.connect`

```
const MongoClient = require("mongodb").MongoClient

MongoClient.connect(uri, (err, client) => {
    if (err){
        console.log(err);
    }
    const database = client.db(databaseName);

    setInterval(function(){
      getData(database, function(data){
        if(data.length > 0){
            db_response = data;
            params["fieldA"] = db_response[0]['fieldA'];
        }
      })
    }, 10000)
 })


function getData(db, callback){
  var query = { fieldA: "foo" };
  db.collection(CollectionName).find(query).toArray(function(err, result){
    if (err){
        throw err;
    }
    callback(result);
  })
}
```

Comment: Yup, that was it!